# What is the difference between WEB-INF and /src/main/resources folders?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, resources, spring-3, web-inf

Which files "specifically" need to be in WEB-INF in a Spring 3 application which uses hibernate? I am also using Maven.

Do certain files in /src/main/resources need to be copied to WEB-INF before the app is run in a production environment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, `WEB-INF` should contain a Web Descriptor `web.xml` and Spring configuration file(s). While the Hibernate configuration file `hibernate.cfg.xml` and other mapping files should put inside `src/main/resources` when development.

> http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html#tutorial-firstapp

This official tutorial from Hibernate tells you some details in what to include in `src/main/resources` and `WEB-INF` which may help you to understand the structure.

> http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example/

Also I found this tutorial quite similar to your case and you may have a reference on it.

*DISCLAIMER: I do not own any of the web tutorial resources.*